# Containerize blockchain microservice

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

If I am hosting my microservice on the host machine it is working as expected but if I host the same thing in a container I am getting these errors:

```
2020-09-27T08:35:06.099Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer2.audit.blockit.co:9050, url:grpcs://localhost:9050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:06.099Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server orderer2.audit.blockit.co:9050 url:grpcs://localhost:9050 timeout:3000
2020-09-27T08:35:06.100Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildOrderer[blockit] - Unable to connect to the discovered orderer orderer2.audit.blockit.co:9050 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Committer- name: orderer2.audit.blockit.co:9050, url:grpcs://localhost:9050, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:09.108Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer2.blockit.co:9051, url:grpcs://localhost:9051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:09.109Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer2.blockit.co:9051 url:grpcs://localhost:9051 timeout:3000
2020-09-27T08:35:09.109Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[blockit] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer2.blockit.co:9051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer2.blockit.co:9051, url:grpcs://localhost:9051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:12.113Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.blockit.co:7051, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:12.114Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.blockit.co:7051 url:grpcs://localhost:7051 timeout:3000
2020-09-27T08:35:12.114Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[blockit] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer0.blockit.co:7051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.blockit.co:7051, url:grpcs://localhost:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:15.118Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer1.blockit.co:8051, url:grpcs://localhost:8051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:15.119Z - error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer1.blockit.co:8051 url:grpcs://localhost:8051 timeout:3000
2020-09-27T08:35:15.119Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[blockit] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer1.blockit.co:8051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer1.blockit.co:8051, url:grpcs://localhost:8051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
2020-09-27T08:35:15.145Z - error: [RoundRobinQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
at RoundRobinQueryHandler.evaluate (/app/microservice/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/roundrobinqueryhandler.js:46:23)
at Transaction.evaluate (/app/microservice/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:278:49)
at FabricRepository.<anonymous> (/app/microservice/dist/services/blockchain-client.js:206:51)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/app/microservice/dist/services/blockchain-client.js:5:58)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5), name=FabricError
queryChaincode Error: Cannot query from blockchain: Query failed. Errors: []
at FabricRepository.<anonymous> (/app/microservice/dist/services/blockchain-client.js:213:23)
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at rejected (/app/microservice/dist/services/blockchain-client.js:6:65)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
POST /fabric-service/queryChaincode 18184.858
```

Any Idea why??

Comment: `localhost` within a container refers to the container itself. Are you sure all the URLs you specified are within the container?

Comment: For my connection profile I am using the container name instead of IP. Something like:
`"url": "grpcs://orderer0.audit.blockit.co:7050"`
That should be resolved right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output here you can see

```
2020-09-27T08:35:15.119Z - error: [DiscoveryService]: _buildPeer[blockit] - Unable to connect to the discovered peer peer1.blockit.co:8051 due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer1.blockit.co:8051, url:grpcs://localhost:8051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
```

that it's trying to connect to localhost:8051. As localhost resolves to the container you are running your app in it won't find it. You are probably resolving to localhost because you have `asLocalHost` set to true for your application
You need to set this option to false and ensure that your app in the container it's in can resolve to the expected hostnames you have defined